# How to implement this table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I really tried hard to do this on my own, but I keep failing ... Using multi-column and multi-row commands confused me. I know some of you might frown upon such a request but I really need help getting this table implemented .. So I'm sorry if I upset anyone.

My preamble has :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
```

[image]

Is there a way I can convert this from excel to LaTeX form ? I tried an add-in before but it didn't work for me. Also online generators cannot combine cells the way I want them (unless I didn't find a better table generator ? )

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33511/14100).  It should contain all of what you need to make your table.

Comment: @ScottH. Thank you, while that certainly makes it easier to do my table, I cannot figure out how to make bottom left portion of the table as it's not covered in the answer. Do you have an idea how can I adapt the answer you provided to implement it ?

Comment: There's a `\multirow` that will span multiple rows.

Comment: To implement this table, you need, as you have discovered, the standard table configurations plus ``multicolumn`` and ``multirow``. All of it should be covered at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables (that's where I learned these things). It would perhaps help us if you could go into more detail about which configurations you're having troubles with. If this is your first time trying to make a LaTeX table, I suggest approaching it step by step by building a simple table first, before you delve into multi-columns/-rows: http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/tables

Comment: @Razor I'm not much of a table expert, was just pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I will look at the links you suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|cc||c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c||}{\multirow{2}{*}{Word}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Word}\\
\cline{3-5}
& & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Word} & \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{1} & & &\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{2} & & &\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{3} & & &\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{4} & & &\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{5} & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time. Now I can continue working on my dissertation :D

Comment: Do you know how can I adjust the width of cells ?? It says I cannot  use the normal `c{0.2\textwidth}` because I'm using `c` ?

Comment: Please have a look at the wiki I linked to in my previous comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. The things you've asked for (tables, multicolumns, multirows, column width) are all explained there. For future reference, you're more likely to receive help if you can show that you have put some effort into solving your problem. That typically includes providing a MWE that illustrates where you get stuck - and - it assumes that you've looked at the links people provide you with.