# How to get single columns and multicolumns in the same table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I want to make a table which looks like following:[image]

I found a question similar to mine situation [How do I create the headings for this multirow multicolum table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33510/how-do-i-create-the-headings-for-this-multirow-multicolum-table). But I am unable to manipulate the code given in the answer to get the desired result. Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way, without `multirow`, and `makecell` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array, makecell}%

\begin{document}

\noindent\sffamily%
\setcellgapes[t]{3.5pt}\makegapedcells%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}%
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{l|}l@{\qquad}l|}
  \hline
TITLE1 & TITLE2 & TITLE3 & TITLE4 & TITLE5 & TITLE6 & TITLE7 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{TITLE8 \\Sub1\quad Sub2}} \\
\hline
A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 & E1 & F1 & G1 & H1 & I1 \\
\hline
A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 & E2 & F2 & G2 & H2 & I2 \\
\hline
A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 & E3 & F3 & G3 & H3 & I3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If I intend to expand and create more columns like Title8, then what changes should I make in the code?

Comment: Add in the preamble other pairs of column specifies like `l@{\qquad}l`, or if there are more consecutive such pairs of columns, `*{n}{l@{\qquad}l}` (n is the number of pairs of columns), and  `\multicolumn`{2}{c|}{\makecell{...}}` for each pair of columns with a common head. Note the value of the spacing between columns (`@{\qquad}`) depends on the real content of the cells.  Also, I doubt it would fit on the page width if there are more columns…